# Ensure that a version of some package is newer than version x

Tags: python, import

is there a better way in python to ensure a script runs only with a version of a module newer than x as this?

```
import somemodule
assert int(somemodule.__version__[0]) > 1 # would enforce a version of at least 2.0
```

In perl one would do it like:

```
use somemodule 2.0
```

I would like to do this because I need a newer version than the one provided by Debian repositories and would like to ensure the user installed the lib via pip.

The point is, the script would run with the older package without errors but produce wrong outcome because of unfixed bugs in the old Debian module version.

PS: I need a solution that works for python2 (2.6/2.7) and python3.

Comment: Why is this method not good enough for you? By printing some meaningful message to the user would be a better solution. Check the version in a `try: except:` clause then raise exception when version is wrong and print the message to indicate that another version should be used.

Comment: I didn't want to say it is not good enough, I just wanted to know if there is a more "pythonic" way of doing this, since I'm fairly new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you really have to convert to int. **I know this is not pythonic way of doing it**, but it definitely works

```
>>> assert('0.0.8' > '1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>> assert('0.0.8' > '0')
>>> assert('0.0.8' > '0.0.7')
>>> assert('0.0.8' > '0.0.7.5')
>>> assert('0.0.8' > '0.0.7.5.8')
>>> assert('0.0.8' > '0.0.8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>> assert('0.0.8' > '0.0.8.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>>
```

what I mean is `assert(somemodule.__version__ > '1')` # raise assertion error if version installed is less than 1

Comment: Good to know :)

I would have added "and int(somemodule.__version__[1]) ..."